# ACF - change link based on backend select choice in a repeater field

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

am using Advanced Custom Fields for many things on my site.  One thing in particular is for a staff profile page.  I have a select field where the staff can add social icons or an email icon.  The repeater field is 'social' and if they choose to 'add a row' there is 'social channel' select field and a 'social_link' test field.  My current code is this:

```
                <?php if ( have_rows('social')): ?>
                    <div class="staff-social">
                        <?php while ( have_rows('social')) : the_row() ?>
                            <li><a href="<?= the_sub_field('link'); ?>"><img src="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/footer-<?php the_sub_field('social_channel') ?>.svg" alt="social icon" /></a></li>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </div><!--end staff-social-->
                <?php endif; ?>
```

I need to prepend a 'mailto:' to my anchor tag if the user selects 'mail' from the 'social_channel' dropdown in the backend.  I have tried doing:

```
                       <?php while ( have_rows('social')) : the_row() ?>
                            <li>
                            <?php $select = get_sub_field_object('social_channel');
                            $choices = $select['choices']; 
                            foreach ($choices as $choice) {
                                if ($choice == 'mail') {
                                    echo '<a href="mailto:'.the_sub_field('link').'">';
                                } else echo '<a href="'.the_sub_field('link').'">';
                            } ?>
                            <img src="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/footer-<?php the_sub_field('social_channel') ?>.svg" alt="social icon" />
                            </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

But this of course spits something out for all choices, whether or not they are selected by the user in the backend.  Can anyone help me with this?  I think this is pretty basic PHP but I'm not sure how to do it.  Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Select field should return just a single string, not an array, **(make sure you set the 'social_channel' field to NOT allow multiple values)** so change your code to this:

```
<?php while ( have_rows('social')) : the_row() ?>
        <li>
            <?php $select = get_sub_field('social_channel');
            if($select == 'mail'){ 
                $linkURL = 'mailto:'.get_sub_field('link');
            }else{
                $linkURL = get_sub_field('link');
            } ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $linkURL; ?>"><img src="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/footer-<?php the_sub_field('social_channel') ?>.svg" alt="social icon" /></a>
        </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you a million times over, Joe!